# Action link sends Id to different area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Say you have two areas (`Area1` and `Area2`) with default routing.  Each of these areas has a Home controller.

Say you have two areas (`Area1` and `Area2`) with default area-aware routing.  Each of these areas has a Home controller with an Index.  In `Area1`'s Home/Index view you put:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Goto Area2", "Index", New With {.area = "Area2"})
```

and in Area2's Home/Index view you put:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Goto Area1", "Index", New With {.area = "Area1"})
```

**Now the problem:**  If you goto `/Area1/Home/Index/1`, the action link tries to send you to `/Area2/Home/Index/1`.  Why?  And how do I get it to not pass that id to the second area?

Thanks for any advice on the matter, its had be stumped for days.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Goto Area1", "Index", New With {.area = "Area1", .id="" })
```

Comment: That does work, but I have mixed feelings about the solution.  It just doesn't feel clean to depend on the routing information where its not needed.  Say you add a new parameter to your action.. that means you need to go update your action links to clear the value?

Comment: You could always write your own Extension method using the tag builder.  But the truth is you are explicitly trying to tell the link to use no value for the routing information.  By default it merges the existing routing data with the new values you provide.

Comment: As a note you will have the same issue if you try to get back to the "root" area.  If you want to link to a controller that is not in an area you will have to use `Area=""`

Comment: Fair point, but issue of going to root makes more sense at least.  To me it feels like when you add route values those are the only ones it should use.  I suppose an extension method is the best way to go.  Thanks for the information

Comment: I don't know much about the overload but you could check if the RouteValueDictionary version only uses the routing values you provide.  Thing is that would look much worse than the `=""`.

Comment: May also check if `.RouteLink` uses the existing route data.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the solution I used.  It allows you to specify an area without manually passing ReouteValue's, and the important part is it will automatically ignore route values you didn't specify.  This may (and probably does) have errors, so be careful if you use it.

```
    Private ReadOnly ValuesToIgnore As String() = New String() {"action", "controller"}
<Extension()> _
Public Function AreaActionLink(ByVal htmlHelper As HtmlHelper,
                               ByVal linkText As String, Optional actionName As String = Nothing,
                               Optional controllerName As String = Nothing,
                               Optional ByVal areaName As String = Nothing,
                               Optional ByVal routeValues As Object = Nothing,
                               Optional htmlAttributes As Object = Nothing) As MvcHtmlString

    Dim rvs = If(routeValues IsNot Nothing, New RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), New RouteValueDictionary())
    Dim values = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(areaName) Then _
        rvs("area") = areaName

    Dim implicitValues = values.Keys.Except(rvs.Keys)
    For Each key In implicitValues.Except(ValuesToIgnore)
        rvs(key) = Nothing
    Next

    Return htmlHelper.ActionLink(
        linkText,
        actionName,
        controllerName,
        rvs,
        htmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)
    )
End Function
```